# Play 2.0: Optional list in query

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to define a route with an optional list as query parameter

```
GET /places controllers.Application.query(filter: Option[Seq[Int]])
```

but getting this error

```
conf/routes - PlayException: Compilation error [`)' expected but `]' found]
```

I know Play 2 handles `Option`s well, and I want it to pass `Seq` to my custom `QueryStringBindable`, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like Play 2.0.2 routing parser doesn't support nesting type parameters. I've found workaround, I've defined alias for `Seq[Int]`:

```
type IntSeq = Seq[Int]
```

and used it instead of original type:

```
GET /places controllers.Application.query(filter: Option[IntSeq])
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: @JacobLyles You could define it anywhere (except for the routes file of course), and then import it by specifying `routesImport += "your.namespace.IntSeq"` in your `Build.scala` settings section.

Comment: Is this still the case in the subsequent Play versions?